# Attempting to get Bitmap pixel from an ImageView's onTouchListener

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I am displaying a Bitmap on an ImageView.  When the ImageView is tapped, I would like to get the pixel x/y coordinates for the Bitmap where it was tapped.  I have registered the ImageView's onTouchListener, and within the onTouch method, I use getX and getY to get the location of the touch.  The problem is that the image within the ImageView may be larger than the view itself, so it is scaled down to fit the screen.  The x and y coordinates returned, then, are the coordinates of the view, but not necessarily the coordinates of the corresponding pixel on the Bitmap.

Can I get some sort of scale factor to know how much it was resized?  Or if not, could someone suggest how I could go about getting the information I need?  What's most important is that I can get the pixel coordinates - if I have to change the view type, that's alright.

Also, sometimes the bitmap is smaller than the screen, so it scales it up.  In this scenario, it is possible that the x and y received from the MotionEvent are outside the bounds of the actual Bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check into the ScaleType property.  You'll have to do the math on the original image, based on the results of getScaleType(), but it's worth checking out.

Comment: The problem with ScaleType is that it just returns the method they use for scaling, not the actual ratio by which it is scaled.

Answer (score 0):

I can across the same case. The thread is more than a year old, but thought it might be useful for someone. I had to scale the bitmap before setting to the ImageView.

Here is the code:

```
//Convert Uri to Bitmap
inputBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

//Scale the bitmap to fit in the ImageView
Bitmap bmpScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inputBitmap, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(),true);

//Set the scaled bitmap to the ImageView
img.setImageBitmap(bmpScaled);
```

After this, the touched coordinates are the same as the coordinates of the bitmap.